# Is there a way to make this query much easier on the server

Tags: php, angularjs

I have made a calendar in angularJs and am using PHP to get all the appointments.

I have a table called 'valuations' with lots of rows, but the main ones are 'Consultant' and 'Appointment'

Currently i'm looping though all the lists of consultants from the consultants table and then checking all the appointments for each one like this :

```
angular.forEach($scope.consultantsApps, function(item,key){

       var appdate = new Date( moment(item.Appointment).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));

//removed my adding to calendar code as its not relevent but here is where i add the appointment to the calendar

                     }

                        });
```

And this is my select which is being run for each consultant in the consultantApps array :

```
<?php
 header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$User = $_GET['user'];

require_once('sqlconnect.php');
$sqlQuery = "SELECT valuations.Company, 
            valuations.Ref, valuations.Appointment, 
            valuations.txtTime,
            valuations.Town,
            valuations.PostCode,
            user.colorcode,
            user.agencyname
            FROM valuations 
            inner join user on user.agencyname = valuations.Consultant
            WHERE user.id = $User order by valuations.Appointment desc LIMIT 20"; 
$result = $unity_connection->query($sqlQuery);

$json1 = array();
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    $json1[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $rows);

}   

    echo json_encode($json1);


?>
```

There are about 20 consultants each with around 400 appointments but ive had to limit to 20 for speed.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should definitively not use $User (which comes from user input) on the request, to prevent from SQL injection. At least you should escape it (with `(int)` or `$pdo->escape`). At best use a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Then, on your request I think you should SELECT on the user table and then make a join on the valuations :

```
SELECT valuations.Company, 
        valuations.Ref, valuations.Appointment, 
        valuations.txtTime,
        valuations.Town,
        valuations.PostCode,
        user.colorcode,
        user.agencyname
        FROM user 
        inner join valuations on user.agencyname = valuations.Consultant
        WHERE user.id = ? order by valuations.Appointment desc LIMIT 20
```

Comment: I want the top 20 appointments for each consultant though, not the top 20 appointments

Comment: Does the `user` table represents the consultants? If yes and if you want the results for each consultant then you shouldn't filter on the `user.id` in the `WHERE` clause, because it is filtering the results on that only user id